# Solving $(x+1)^2-x^2=0$ two ways gives different results

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In mathematics, there are several method of finding the solution of a particular problem. But in this equation,
$$(x+1)^2-x^2=0$$

**Method 1**

Using, $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$,

$$x^2+2x+1-x^2=0$$
So, $x=-1/2$ is the solution.

**Method 2**

$$(x+1)^2-x^2=0$$
$$(x+1)^2=x^2$$
$$x+1=x$$
$$1=0$$
But it is not possible.

> So, what am I missing in this question? Please explain to me.

Comment: $a^{2}=b^{2}$ only gives $a =\pm b$.

Comment: Why do your equations have both X and x? That's very confusing!

Answer (score 6):

Another way to see what went wrong is to use the factorization $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$ like this:

$$(x+1)^2-x^2=0\\(x+1+x)(x+1-x)=0\\x+1+x=0~~~~\text{ or }~~~~x+1-x=0\\x=-\frac12~~~~\text{ or }~~~~1=0$$
Of the two resulting equations, only the first gives a valid solution for $x$. So in this case there is no $a-b=0$ solution, only an $a+b=0$ one. Using this factorization is of course completely equivalent to going from $a^2=b^2$ to $a=\pm b$ directly.

Comment: 1¹=1 , 1⁰=1 . From these equation 1=0 . How is it possible?

Comment: @VaibhavTiwari $1^0=1^1=1^2=1^3=1^4....$ Why would you think this means that $0=1=2=3=4$?

Comment: Yes , why is it not possible . There isn't any mistake . Pls explain me what's wrong

Comment: $x\rightarrow 1^x$ is a constant function. It is not an injective function, so cannot be inverted. You cannot uniquely determine $x$ from the value $1^x$.

Comment: Alternatively: $1^2=1^3 \implies \log(1^2)=\log(1^3) \implies 2\log(1)=3\log(1)$ This does not mean that $2=3$ because actually $\log(1)=0$.

Answer (score 5):

When you take square root, you have to consider two possible sign.

$$x+1 = \pm x$$

After which, we reject one solution, and we have $x+1 = -x$ and conclude that $x= -\frac12$.

Comment: 1¹=1 , 1⁰=1 . From these equation 1=0 . How is it possible?

Comment: note that in general, $f(x)=f(y)$, we can't conclude that $x=y$.